# Rectangle shape with custom side using XML

Tags: android

Is it possible to create a shape like this white rectangle? with that kind of side in the [image]bottom?

Comment: Chcek [ZigzagView](https://github.com/beigirad/ZigzagView)

Answer (score 1):

here it will help you

XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#90000000"
tools:context=".DataGet">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv1"
    android:id="@+id/iv2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv2"
    android:id="@+id/iv3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv3"
    android:id="@+id/iv4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv4"
    android:id="@+id/iv5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv5"
    android:id="@+id/iv6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv6"
    android:id="@+id/iv7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv7"
    android:id="@+id/iv8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv9"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv9"
    android:id="@+id/iv10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv10"
    android:id="@+id/iv11"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv11"
    android:id="@+id/iv12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv12"
    android:id="@+id/iv13"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv13"
    android:id="@+id/iv14"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv14"
    android:id="@+id/iv15"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv15"
    android:id="@+id/iv16"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_flip_1"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>
```

The Above code is simple to create a layout with a background with text View and have a linear layout on it to show Effect like card view.

You have to create a drawable name as "bg_flip_1" if you are coping above code
else you can give your name and replace it with bg_flip_1 in XML file

Drawable will look like

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="100dp"
android:width="100dp"
android:viewportHeight="100"
android:viewportWidth="100" >
<group
    android:name="triableGroup">
    <path
        android:name="triangle"
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M 0,20 L 0,0 L 100,0 L 100,20 L 54,55  l -1,0.6  l -1,0.4  l -1,0.2  l -1,0   l -1,-0  l -1,-0.2  l -1,-0.4  l -1,-0.6    L 46,55   L 0,20 -100,-100 Z" />
</group>
```

The Above code will Create a Triangle vector which we will use for making the below sharp shape

here the triangle will look like this
[image]

After implementing both will look like this

here is screenshot
[image]

Comment: is this way is correct to answer Yunnosch?

Comment: Better now, nice edit. Please understand that I lack the knowledge to tell whether it is good code and explanation, so I cannot vote. But it looks like an explained answer now. I guess others are more likely to upvote now. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way is to import an SVG of the rectangle (Resource manager > '+' > Import drawables), which Android Studio would convert to an XML drawable resource.